# Angular 8 Elements Fail in ie11. Zone.JS loaded twice

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, element

Our Angular Library which is being build as a web component throws an error in IE11.

> 'Zone Already Loaded Error' at runtime in the browser.

The only polyfill I have is import 'zone.js/dist/zone', So I expect I will need to add more polyfills for this to work in IE11.

Removing the above polyfill breaks for both chrome and mozilla.

We've tried pulling in all the polyfills from core-js to no avail

The bundle should load in IE11.

Comment: Hi Arthis12 & welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not going to downvote, because I believe the community demonstrated it's opinion of this question already. **Consider updating your question with a single clearly defined issue, show the effort & research you've done already to solve that issue, and ask a well defined question.**

Comment: Im not sure how I could make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the index.html file, perhaps you are using the following code to add the zone.js again in this file. Try to remove it.

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

Comment: We are not adding the reference, only in the polyfills.

Comment: when you meet this issue? which package are you installed and will cause this issue? I have tried to create a new Angular 8 application, it works well on my side. You could try to create a new application to verify it. if still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).